# using sed to search and replace URLs except in certain cases

Tags: regex, sed

I have a list of urls where, for the majority, I want to do a simple search and replace, but in some cases I want to exclude using sed.

Given the list below:

```
http://www.dol.gov 
http://www.science.gov 
http://www.whitehouse.gov 
http://test.sandbox.local 
http://www.travel.state.gov 
http://www.lib.berkeley.edu
http://dev.sandbox.local
```

I want to convert all URLs that do not have "sandbox" in the URL to:

```
href="/fetch?domain=<url>"
```

What I have so far with sed is the following:

```
sed -r 's|http://(\S*)|href="/fetch\?domain=\1"|g'
```

which reformats all the URLs as expected.

How do I modify what I have to exclude the lines that have "sandbox" in them?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by exclude, you mean "do not do the replacement", then:

```
sed -r '/sandbox/!s|http://(\S*)|href="/fetch\?domain=\1"|g'
```

If you mean 'omit completely from the output':

```
sed -r -e '/sandbox/d' -e 's|http://(\S*)|href="/fetch\?domain=\1"|g'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -r 's|http://(\S*)|href="/fetch\?domain=\1"|g' | grep -v sandbox
```